# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity : java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, wikitude

I am facing issue with my code.I am getting RuntimeException.Kindly please do help me with this.

I'm getting the following error log :

`06-17 18:11:32.646 13750-13750/? E/Zygote: v2
06-17 18:11:32.646 13750-13750/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
06-17 18:11:33.226 13750-13750/com.example.cocol.timisoara2021 E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@f847827
06-17 18:11:33.226 13750-13750/com.example.cocol.timisoara2021 E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@d2d3ad4
06-17 18:11:33.226 13750-13750/com.example.cocol.timisoara2021 E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@d2d3ad4
06-17 18:11:36.566 13750-14348/com.example.cocol.timisoara2021 E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
06-17 18:11:36.666 13750-13750/com.example.cocol.timisoara2021 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.cocol.timisoara2021, PID: 13750
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.cocol.timisoara2021/com.example.cocol.timisoara2021.Main2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.wikitude.common.orientation.internal.a.a()' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4226)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4328)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3427)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7407)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.wikitude.common.orientation.internal.a.a()' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectView.onResume(ProGuard:818)
                                                                                     at com.example.cocol.timisoara2021.Main2Activity.onResume(Main2Activity.java:59)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1287)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7015)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4215)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4328) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3427) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7407) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)` 
And here is the line 53:architectView.onResume();

And the code:

```
package com.example.cocol.timisoara2021;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectStartupConfiguration;
import com.wikitude.architect.ArchitectView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ArchitectView architectView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        this.architectView = (ArchitectView) this.findViewById(R.id.architectView);

        final ArchitectStartupConfiguration config = new ArchitectStartupConfiguration();
        config.setLicenseKey("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");
        this.architectView.onCreate(config);

    }


    protected void OnPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        architectView.onPostCreate();

        try {
            this.architectView.load("file:///android_asset/POI/index.html");
        }catch (Exception e) {


        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        architectView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        architectView.onResume();

    }

    @Override

    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        architectView.onDestroy();
    }




}
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: try this in onresume : if(architectView!=null){architectView.onResume();}

Comment: paste your log not image

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work :( same error

Answer (score 0):

Your onPostCreate method has an uppercase "O". Because of this i assume it is never called which means that the ArchitectView is in an invalid state when you call architectView.onResume.

Try:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    architectView.onPostCreate();
    try {
        this.architectView.load("file:///android_asset/POI/index.html");
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```